# COMBINING INDEX WITH LINEST

Tags: excel

I want to write a VBA function making use of LINEST excel function to calculate some tstats for the slope. I know that i have to combine the INDEX function with the LINEST function, but i don't know how. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please be more specific and detailed. What are you specifically trying to do (what is the exact problem)? Sample data and expected output. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: tstat is pretty specific, guys.  Give Jane a break.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need VBA...

Follow the [standard Excel LINEST syntax](http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/PChem/notes/linest.pdf).  Use the LINEST function to return m and b (as in, y = mx + b) to a place on another sheet.

I'll assume your x's are in column A and your y's are in column B, and that the list is only 10 items long.  Over at Sheet 2, select cells A1 : B1 and make this formula:

=LINEST(Sheet1!B1:B10, Sheet1!A1:A10, FALSE, TRUE)

...makings sure to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> after you enter this formula to tell Excel to handle it as an array function.  (you'll know this worked because Excel uses {} to show functions that are array functions.)

Now cells A1 and B1 are slope and offset.

Back on Sheet 1, in column C, use this formula to insert the linear line:

=A1 * Sheet2!$A$1 + Sheet2!$B$1

...and you should be good to go!  Note that LINEST can do lots more reporting if you let it... follow the instructions on [the link](http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/PChem/notes/linest.pdf) to see how.